# 6 dice are tossed one by one, the probability that all dice show 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, dice

I'm working on this problem.

6 dice are tossed, what's the probability that all dice 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order.

Comment: How do we get numbers in order if the dice are tossed simultaneously?

Comment: Assuming they all land simultaneously as well, the probability of landing in order is zero .... Maybe it's a trick question?!

Comment: total possible choices are 6^6

Comment: Maybe they are coloured dice and we take results in ROYGBV placement, or they are rolled against a stopper board, such as on a crap table, or some such order imposing structure.

Comment: I assumed they were tossed at the same time, but it isnt, it's one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of rolling $123456$ with six dice in a single roll can be expressed as: $$P(\text {second die does not match first die})\times P(\text {third die does not match first or second die}) \times \cdots$$ $$ = 1\times \frac {5}{6} \times \frac {4}{6} \times \frac {3}{6} \times \frac {2}{6} \times \frac {1}{6} = 0.015432$$

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about if the dice are tossed one by one?

Comment: @ColonelG If tossed one by one, then the outcome of one die is not affected by the outcome of the others, so we have a probability of $(\frac{1}{6})^6$.